# Is it possible create a graphql type using an enum for the property name?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I have an enum and I'm trying to use the enum to create a GraphQl type. Each property in this new type can be optional. Each type returns the same type.

Here's an example of the Enum:

```
enum AccountTypeEnum {
 AccountType1
 AccountType2
 AccountType3
 AccountType4
 AccountType5
 AccountType6
}
```

I'd like to create a type using the enum so I don't need to type out each one. This is a shortened down version, but there's over 20 accountTypes - each returning an array of balances.

This is what i'd like the type to look like:

```
type BalanceList {
 AccountType1: [Balances]
 AccountType2: [Balances]
 AccountType3: [Balances]
 AccountType4: [Balances]
 AccountType5: [Balances]
 AccountType6: [Balances]
}
```

Is it possible to create BalanceList without typing out the entire Enum?

Also, for each Id there might be only a few of the AccountTypes so I would need to account for that. For example: user 1 could have AccountTypes 1 and 3 (only AccountType1 and AccountType3 would appear on the reponse object, none of the other AccountTypes would be exist on the object)

I couldn't find this in the documentation so I'm not sure if this is possible

Comment: You can manually construct types, and that means you can also construct them programmatically. How are you creating your schema?

Comment: @Bergi I'm constructing it using the apollo client documentation. I create a Schema using : export const schema = [``]

Comment: @Bergi I also had a secondary question, how can I create a fragment on the frontend using only `gql` to create the queries so that I can query all possible account types?

Comment: Wait, why do you want this as a client schema? And no, it's not possible to use `gql` to construct a query dynamically - but you can manipulate the AST afterwards.

Comment: If you want a query that gets all possible account types, you really should consider a different structure for your schema, like a list of account objects, where each object has a type and balances.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure I follow when you mentioned a different structure for my schema. What do you mean by that? I'm not aware of another structure I could use.

Comment: `type BalanceListEntry { type: AccountTypeEnum; balances: [Balances] }` then use `[BalanceListEntry]` instead of `BalanceList`.

Comment: @bergi but this would fail, because the key in the object is not called `type`, it could be any/multiple of `AccountTypeEnum`

Comment: You'll need to transform the object obviously to fit the other schema, like `Object.entries` does.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry I dont follow, what do you mean by using `Object.entries`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a programmatic schema, you could build it when the server starts. You have been presenting your schema in the Schema Definition Language (SDL), but you could probably build a part of it at run time and pass it to [typeDefs and resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#typedefs) together with the rest your SDL schema.

It's complicated, and it's probably a bad idea. Having a static schema has many advantages, and it's one of the values of GraphQL. A static schema is easy to diagnose. It allows the validity of queries to be checked at build time by lots of tools (maybe you don't need it now, but the need might arise). If your objective is to avoid maintaining 20 lines of code, it might not be worth it.

What I think you want is to redesign your schema so that the "dynamic" part becomes part of the modelled data. Here is an example:

```
type BalanceList {
  balancesByType: [AccountTypeBalance!]!
}
type AccountTypeBalance {
  accountType: AccountTypeEnum!
  balances: [Balance!]!
}
```

It can be simplified. Assuming that you intend to use `BalanceList` in a `User` type, you might not even need the `BalanceList` type. How about the following

```
type User {
  balanceList: [AccountTypeBalance!]!
}
```

This is great for your bonus requirement, because now for user1 you can return a balanceList with only two elements. Here is what a result could look like:

```js
const user = {
  id: "user1",
  balanceList: [
    { accountType: "AccountType1", balances: [ balance1, balance2 ] },
    { accountType: "AccountType3", balances: [ balance3, balance4, balance5 ] },
  ],
};
```